# Where can I find more Eridium?

Tags: borderlands-2

I got a pop-up saying I can find it in missions, enemies, and treasure chests. Are *all* Eridium spawns random? Does the Eridium supply have a cutoff? Do certain chests or enemies in certain areas/locations always drop Eridium? Can I reduce the Eridium costs at Crazy Earl's/the Black Market to maximize the Eridium I do find? Where are the best locations to farm Eridium? What are the most time- and cost-effective methods for farming it?

[image: Eridium]

Comment: I found a strange thing, the wall lockers inside the crimson raiders HQ very often have Eridium inside of them. Far more than I find outside of the HQ.

Answer (score 17):

According to the [Borderlands 2 Wikia page related to Eridium](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Eridium):

> So far it is unknown if there is a sure-fire way to obtain Eridium, but it is an uncommon-rare drop by certain enemies and rarely found in containers like lockers and washing machines. You can also obtain it by playing the slot machines at Moxxxi's place in Sanctuary.

#### Moxxxi's slot machines

According to [this article](http://venturebeat.com/2012/09/17/breaking-borderlands-2-easy-money-xp-eridium-boss-fights-and-tokens/) the following is a list of potential payouts from playing the slot machines - in addition to randomly generated weapons and items of course;

- x3 Bandits: Live grenade (Run!)
- x3 7s: Customization skin
- x3 Cherries: Green item
- x3 Legs: Blue item
- x3 Marcus: Purple item
- x3 Borderlands logo: Orange item
- x3 Eridium Bar (1): 4 Eridium
- x3 Eridium Bars (2): 8 Eridium
- x3 Eridium Stack (3): 16 Eridium (!!!!)
- Any two with non-bell: White weapon
- Any two with bell at end: Cash

It is worth noting that playing the slot machines at Moxxxi's place will get more expensive as you progress through the game, yet some of the items you can win by playing the slots scale with your character - this means that playing the slots at a lower level will cost less while still potentially providing benefit to you at the later levels.

Comment: Also of important note is that Eridium, like cash and ammo, is given to all players in a co-op session. So you can get four people together and spam the slot machine. Everyone benefits!

Comment: Per http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/85000/1134 rewards can also include: Any two with non-bell: White weapon, Any two with bell at end: Cash

Answer (score 6):

I have bought everything Crazy Earl has to offer and have then gone on to save a further 99 blocks of eridium. You cannot save any more than this. You can pick up the excess eridium, but it won't add to your tally.

Later on in the game, eridium drops become more common from defeated enemies. Earlier on you can scavenge plenty in Sanctuary, especially by checking inside the Crimson Raiders' HQ.

It can be found in lockers and cardboard boxes.

Comment: You can spend that E on doing Terramorphous runs (4 units per shot).

Comment: As of July 2013 you can save more than 99 eridium; I've had over 200 at a time. I don't know whether this is because of DLC or general game updates.

Answer (score 6):

The warrior is by far the best place to farm Eridium if you need it for your alt characters. It drops 20-30 Eridium each time and can be defeated in about a minute with normal level 50 guns. Time is dropped to about 30 sec with good legendary weapons.

Answer (score 2):

GOD-liaths always drop at least a few Eridium when killed. I use this method a lot and now I've bought most stuff in the Black Market. Playing the slots is a good method as well early on.