# What kinds of things can I win by gambling?

Tags: borderlands-2

What kinds of things can I win by playing the slots in Moxxi's and what combinations payout?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Compiling personal experience and resources online, I have found the following combination of rewards:

- Any two with non-bell: White weapon
- Any two with bell at end: Cash
- x3 Bells: Lots of cash
- x3 Bandits: Live grenade
- x3 7's: Random Manufacturer Character Skin (i.e Tediore, Vladof, etc.)
- x3 Cherries: Green Weapon
- x3 Legs: Blue Weapon or Purple Weapon
- x3 Marcus: Purple Weapon
- x3 Borderlands logo: Orange Weapon
- x3 Eridium Bar (1): 4 Eridium
- x3 Eridium Bars (2): 8 Eridium
- x3 Eridium Stack (3): 16 Eridium

Comment: I wonder if someone could count probabilities of every combination and average amount of money spent to get orange/eridium...

Comment: @FrantisekKossuth It may not be completely random. I've noticed some weird results by attempting to pull both leavers at the same time.

Answer (score 8):

[This answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/84859/3107) by [@pixel](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/27134/pixel) to a different question covers the slot machine rewards. Since the topic of that question is substantially different, though ([how to farm Eridium](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/84855/3107)), I'll reproduce it here:

> According to [this article](http://venturebeat.com/2012/09/17/breaking-borderlands-2-easy-money-xp-eridium-boss-fights-and-tokens/) the following is a list of potential payouts from playing the slot machines - in addition to randomly generated weapons and items of course;
>
> - x3 Bandits: Live grenade (Run!)
> - x3 7s: Customization skin
> - x3 Cherries: Green weapon
> - x3 Legs: Blue weapon
> - x3 Marcus: Purple weapon
> - x3 Borderlands logo: Orange weapon
> - x3 Eridium Bar (1): 4 Eridium
> - x3 Eridium Bars (2): 8 Eridium
> - x3 Eridium Stack (3): 16 Eridium (!!!!)
>
> It is worth noting that playing the slot machines at Moxxxi's place will get more expensive as you progress through the game, yet some of the items you can win by playing the slots scale with your character - this means that playing the slots at a lower level will cost less while still potentially providing benefit to you at the later levels.

Comment: You do sometimes get a payout by only matching 2 of a certain symbol

Comment: My boyfriend got 3 borderlands symbols and I think it was an Orange item. I'm not positive, but I don't see Orange items on your list and I know we got at least one from gambling :)