# What happens if you get all Vault signs on the slots?

Tags: borderlands-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What kinds of things can I win by gambling?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/84987/what-kinds-of-things-can-i-win-by-gambling)

While gambling on the slot machines, what would happen if you were to get all three vault signs?