# What are the odds on the slot machines?

Tags: borderlands-2

I've seen [what I can win](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/84987/9300) in the *Borderlands 2* slot machines, I'm curious to know what the **odds of winning** each are.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a pie chart and list with all items / probabilities:

<sup>[Source: Orcz Wiki, "Borderlands 2: Moxxi Slot Machines Odds Probabilities Statistics"](http://orcz.com/Borderlands_2:_Moxxi_Slot_Machines_Odds_Probabilities_Statistics)</sup>

> These are the results of spinning the Slot Machines from Borderlands 2
> at Moxxxis 22,362 times:
>
> [image]
>
> Detailed Results (Combination, Prize, Number of Spins, Percentage)
> from most frequently occurring to most rarely occurring:
>
> TOTAL SPINS: 22,362
>
> 2 Same Symbols With Bell - (Cash) 5216 (23.33%)
> No Match -  4708 (21.05%)
> 2 Same Symbols Without Bell - (White Weapon)    4513 (20.18%)
> 3 Cherries - (Green Weapon) 3179 (14.22%)
> 3 Psychos - (Live Grenade)  2387 (10.67%)
> 3 7s - (Custom Skin)    981 (4.39%)
> 3 Single Eridium - (4x Eridium) 602 (2.69%)
> 3 Moxxi Legs - (Blue Item)  327 (1.46%)
> 2 Bells - (Cash)    190 (0.85%)
> 3 Double Eridium - (8x Eridium) 165 (0.74%)
> 3 Marcus - (Purple Weapon)  41 (0.18%)
> 3 Triple Eridium - (12x Eridium)    39 (0.17%)
> 3 Bells - (Lots of cash)    9 (0.04%)
> 3 Borderlands Vault Symbol (JACKPOT) - (Orange Weapon)  5 (0.02%)

Found this while doing a quick search for the statistical numbers. There is also a chart that shows the different percentages for each of them.

Comment: The link Robert A Palmer posted has been consistent with my results as well, though I thinks chance for vaults is slightly lower (I got the jackpot after like 3,500 spins) though it could've been bad luck

Comment: Of course you can't judge probabilities against a single occurrence :-) (Not to doubt your general observations, of course!)

Comment: 0.04% for legendary weapons. Well $#!%

Comment: I don't suppose the machine on One Armed Bandits has different odds or does anyone know?