# What is the easiest way to gain Eridium?

Tags: borderlands-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find more Eridium?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/84855/where-can-i-find-more-eridium)

I'm looking to get a lot of Backpack upgrades and Ammo upgrades, but one thing I'm having trouble finding is Eridium.  Do certain areas have more eridium than others?  Or is it set at the same drop rate from all enemies?

Comment: Loads of enemies drop it, especially at higher levels. You'll probably find that you have all you need to buy everything before you get to level 50. Once you have you need 4-8 for each raid-boss encounter, but by the time you get to them you'll probably have maxed it out (you can't carry more than 99 and level 50 enemies drop it all the time).

Comment: The *easiest* way is to run around and open many containers :) But yes, as linked answer states, no special way. Kill, loot.

Comment: If you open every container in Sanctuary, you can usually find a few.  It's also beneficial to join a game with friends and take turns playing slots, you all get the same amount of eridium if one of you wins.  Using that method, I maxed out my SDUs by around level 35.  Once you start TVHM, there is more than you'll need dropped.